# PHP Get Current Input Value and New Submitted Value

Tags: php, forms, get, amember

I've got a profile page that shows a users current account number in an input field. The user can change this account number and submit the form to update the database with their new account number.

What I need to do is get the initial account number, as well as the new submitted account number so I can use them in another script that runs on the same page.

```
$user = Am_Di::getInstance()->auth->getUser();

$oldnum = $user->accountnumber;
$newnum = $_GET['accountnumber'];

$client2 = $api->findClient( mlApi::LICENSE_ACCOUNT, $oldnum );


$client = array( 'account_no' => $newnum, 'real_demo' => '1', 'comment' => 'test2' );

$api->updateClient( mlApi::LICENSE_ACCOUNT, $client2[_index], $client );
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem here? Can you be precise?

Comment: If I have understood the question well, then you should use a hidden type input with value of initial account number. Then even if the use enters the new account number, the initial one will also be available on the submitted page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep a value saved for future use there is two common ways (could be other ways) of handling it.

1. Save it in the session
2. Rendering as a hidden form element in the user form and read it back from the client.

The latter has a 100% security problem because a malicious user can change this id before the next request comes. To demonstrate how

```
<input type='hidden' name='account_id' value='<?php echo $account?>' />
<input type='text' name='account_id_text' value='<?php echo $account?>' />
```

This method use is highly discouraged.

The first method, using the session is the safest mechanism of all.

To utilize that

```
 $_SESSION['account_id'] = $account_id;
 //render the view here
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Problem is I have to use $user->accountnumber; to fetch the account number from the database, so its always taking the updated entry from the db.

Comment: you can compare it with the value from session